# How array has been accessed with an illegal index

Tags: java, arrays

I am new in java and witing a programm to delete an element with specific position. I know there are many possible answer but i am trying here my own.
I am getting the error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9
                                at 
Array.DeleteElement.delete(DeleteElement.java:24)
                                at 
Array.DeleteElement.main(DeleteElement.java:14)
```

Now Here I am passing array and position. Where it is getting incorrect index. As per documentaion it is saying array has been accessed with an illegal index.
Can anybody please explain me how it is illegal and where I am getting wrong.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    //int[] delArray = new int[15]; 
    int[] delArray = {20,50,60,9,8,7,1,5,3};
    System.out.println("Enter Element you want to delete");
    int del = in.nextInt();
    int pos = InsertSearch.searchKey(delArray,del);
    System.out.println(pos);
    if(pos != -1){
        delete(delArray,del,pos);
        for(int i=0; i<delArray.length; i++)
            System.out.println(delArray[i]);
    }
    else 
        System.out.println(del+"Not exist in array");
}

public static int delete(int delArr[], int del, int pos){
    for(int i=pos; i<delArr.length; i++)
        delArr[i] = delArr[i+1];
    return delArr.length -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look,

```
public static int delete(int delArr[], int del, int pos){
    for(int i=pos; i<delArr.length; i++)
        delArr[i] = delArr[i+1];   //<---- HERE
    return delArr.length -1;
}
```

in this loop, `i` goes up to the max index of the array, but inside, you access `i+1`th element which in this case causes `IndexOutOfBoundsException` being thrown.

From the stacktrace, you can read, that you tried to access 9th element but your array has only indexes from 0 to 8 incl.

Comment: Oh.. got it. It means when it try to access for last index `del[i+1]` is not getting. perfect explanation. thanks

Comment: I am sorry but I don't how to read stack trace. any link for that will be helpfull.

Comment: @shankysingh http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Comment: Ya, I got the desire result. Will accept answer after 8 min :)

Comment: @shankysingh cool, thanks. Also, pro-tip - use brackets even if they aren't obligatory. Wrap {single line}

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
delArr[i] = delArr[i+1];
```

When `i` is equal to `8`, then `i+1` gives `9`, which generates the Exception

Answer (score 1):

This snippet of code is problem

```
for(int i=pos; i<delArr.length; i++)
    delArr[i] = delArr[i+1];
```

Precisely, `delArr[i] = delArr[i+1]`. The issue is `i+1`.
In Java indices in an array starts with 0, and the last index is N-1 for the array which has length N.
You loop should be `for(int i=pos; i<delArr.length-1; i++)`.